# spleeter separate video file to vocals and accompaniment, length of time is different

Tags: spleeter

I want to use spleeter to spleeter separate video file  to vocals audio and accompaniment audio,but length of time is different.
This is the command below.

```
spleeter separate "[file path].mp4" -p spleeter:2stems -o "[folder path]"
```

Input file mp4 time : about 13 minutes

Output file wav time : about 10 minutes

How to keep time length of media file after using spleeter separate command?

Answer (score 0):

This is because duration limitation.

```
$ spleeter separate --help
Usage: spleeter separate [OPTIONS] FILES...

  Separate audio file(s)

Arguments:
  FILES...  List of input audio file path  [required]

Options:


  -d, --duration FLOAT            Set a maximum duration for processing audio
                                  (only separate offset + duration first
                                  seconds of the input file)  [default: 600.0]
```